# Upgrade to wordpress 4.2.4 breaks all categories

Tags: wordpress

I just updated [my blog](http://homenewdesign.com/). All of my categories have just broken (404), I have disabled all my plugins still no luck.

I tried creating a new category still nothing. Any ideas please?

Comment: server logs, access logs? Your configuration?

Comment: Just found this https://wordpress.org/support/topic/cannot-upload-new-files-anymore-404-error-424-issue All I needed to do was go into Settings -> Permalinks and save changes and it fixed the issue.

Comment: Please answer your own question and mark it as answered since you've found the solution. Thanks.